# Merge two multidimensional string arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have (at least) two multidimensional String arrays (with UNequal dimensions), that I am trying to put side by side. That is,

`String[][] arrayOne` contains the following:

```
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
```

...and `String[][] arrayTwo` contains the following:

```
bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbb
```

...and `String[][] arrayThree` contains the following:

```
ccccccc
ccccccc
ccccccc
ccccccc
ccccccc
ccccccc
ccccccc
ccccccc
```

What I have been unsuccessfully trying to do is create a method which returns the following (preferrably as a multidimensional String array, but as a String works too):

`String[][] result` contains the following:

```
               ccccccc
               ccccccc
aaaaa          ccccccc
aaaaa          ccccccc
aaaaa          ccccccc
aaaaa bbbbbbbb ccccccc
aaaaa bbbbbbbb ccccccc
aaaaa bbbbbbbb ccccccc
aaaaa bbbbbbbb ccccccc
```

So basically, the method would put the arrays side-by-side, align them all to the bottom, and combine them into one array.

So far, my complex attempts to solve this problem have only created more errors, and trying to debug with println statements and the like has only confused me more. And I figured someone mush known a fairly easy way to accomplish this task.

If anyone knows, your help would be greatly appreciated!!!

**EDIT - ** Example #2:

```
aaaa            bbb            ccccc                       ccccc
aaaa   'plus'   bbb   'plus'   ccccc   'yields'   aaaa     ccccc
aaaa                           ccccc              aaaa bbb ccccc
                               ccccc              aaaa bbb ccccc
```

Comment: Can we see those errors in your effort?

Comment: plzsendtehcodes you have tried

Comment: your `arrayOne`, `arrayTwo` and `arrayThree` seem to be onedimensional.

Comment: Honestly, the methods I was trying to use were way to confusing, and I can't even narrow it down to a specific point in my code, and I have given up on them. If you know a relatively 'easy' way to do this, it would be great if you could show me your code or explain your logic. Thanks!

Comment: I can't tell what needs to be done; why is even more obscure.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that each letter is an element in each array (if that helps any).

Comment: In your final array, do you want the empty spaces to just contain `null`?

Comment: @A.R.S. Multidimensional arrays are jagged in Java, so that would be unnecessary if I'm reading this vague question correctly.

Comment: @PaulBellora Oh, well I was under the impression that he wanted to keep the array square for some reason - maybe you're right.

Comment: @PaulBellora - The array doesn't, and probably won't be, square in the end. I also just added another example to my question (remember, each letter is an element in the array), if that helps any.

Comment: @A.R.S. - the empty spaces are filled with spaces (" "), as strings.

Comment: But if the spaces are filled with `" "` strings, won't the array be square? Also, can we assume that your initial arrays will always be square?

Comment: @A.R.S. - the empty spaces that I'm referring to are the ones between the arrays (the columns of spaces between them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An (untested) general solution to your problem:

**EDIT:** *Thanks you @Paul Bellora for testing and confirming.*

```
public static <T> T[][] mergeArrays(Class<T> clazz, T[][]... arrays) {
    // determine length of 1st dimension.
    int dim1 = 0;
    for (T[][] arr : arrays) {
        dim1 += arr.length;
    }
    // Create new 2Dim Array
    T[][] result = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(clazz, dim1, 0);
    // Fill the new array with all 'old' arrays
    int index = 0;
    for (T[][] arr : arrays) {
        for (T[] array : arr) {
            // changes within your old arrays will reflect to merged one
            result[index++] = array;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is how you call it:

```
    String[][] one = // your 1st array here;
    String[][] two = // your 2nd array here;
    String[][] three = // your 3rd array here;
    String[][] four = // your 4th array here;
    // This works with an arbitrary amount of arrays.
    String[][] merged1 = mergeArrays(String.class, one, two, three);
    String[][] merged2 = mergeArrays(String.class, one, two, three, four);
```

Comment: I have never dealt with <T> (I'm no java expert :]), so, do you think you could rewrite it for multidimensional String arrays? Thanks for helping!

Comment: @iphonedev7 in your case multidemensional = two-dimensional

Comment: You can actually further generalize `mergeArrays` by replacing all `T[]` with `T` (and `T[][]` with `T[]`), and changing `Array.newInstance(clazz, dim1, 0)` to `Array.newInstance(clazz, dim1)`. You would then call `mergeArrays(String[].class, arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree)`.

Comment: But `Array.newInstance(clazz, dim1)` would create a one-dimensional array, so you couldn't put arrays in it.

Comment: @jlordo Multidimensional arrays in Java are just arrays of arrays. The caller would be creating a 1D array of `String[]` if that makes sense - try it and see.

Comment: just thought of that, too, can you confirm that it works? Sorry i overread the `String[].class` in your method call

Comment: I am trying to print out my combined array as a string, but it seems to be having errors. Do you know how to convert the array to a string (with newline characters and everything)??? (I though I had it figured out, but maybe I don't understand how your method works well enough)

Comment: you can print my combined array the same way you printed your original arrays, because it's also a two dimensional array.

Comment: But when I try to do that, they still are printed out on top of each other. I'm using NetBeans IDE, if that helps any.

Comment: **WAIT** is your question on how to merge the arrays (my answer), **OR** how to print them next to each other??

Comment: @iphonedev7 You should really just upvote and accept this answer, then ask a new one if you can't figure out how to print the contents of the array.

Comment: I just read this in your question: 'the method would put the arrays side-by-side, align them all to the bottom, and combine them into one array'. **Combining** arrays and **Printing** arrays aligned next to each other are two completely different things.

Comment: If you want them printed in your format, you shouldn't combine them in the first place.

Comment: @PaulBellora - Maybe, but my intent here (which I guess I didn't express well enough), was to make the arrays print next to each other, which I couldn't find an answer for anywhere else (when I googled it).

Comment: I guess it could be done with a `StringBuilder`, but I see no good reason to do such a thing. Anyway, now I have a method to combine arrays, if I ever need it ;)

Comment: @jlordo - I agree, but do you know a way to put them side-by-side?...Please!?, I am still quite lost. :(

Comment: The code would be really messy. Ask a new question with a title like 'Printing String array contents side by side'. BTW, for what would that be good? The code wouldn't even be nice for onedimensional arrays.

Comment: @iphonedev7 It's a non-trivial problem because of the rotation of what you want printed. It's in your best interest to create a new post since a new wave of people will see it, instead of just jlordo and me in this comment thread (and I'm frankly ready to move on).

Comment: I am trying to print out shapes of characters side-by-side, and if they are on top of each other, it sort of ruins the output.

Comment: @PaulBellora - Alright, I guess if multiple people are saying that, then I'd better just go ahead and do it...Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: I did something similar once, used `char[][]` for 'shapes' and put them all in a `char[][][]`. You have to figure out how much space to add aon the top and iterate through the arrays. My code is here: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Nwg3zMaa) , but i don't think it will be big help

Answer (score 0):

As  requested, just a `String` version, still untested:

```
public static String[][] mergeStringArrays(String[][]... arrays) {
    // determine length of 1st dimension.
    int dim1 = 0;
    for (String[][] arr : arrays) {
        dim1 += arr.length;
    }
    // Create new 2Dim Array
    String [][] result = new String[dim1][];
    // Fill the new array with all 'old' arrays
    int index = 0;
    for (String[][] arr : arrays) {
        for (String[] array : arr) {
            // changes within your old arrays will reflect to merged one
            result[index++] = array;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Look at my first answer to see how to call this method.

Comment: I am trying to print out my combined array as a string, but it seems to be having errors. Do you know how to convert the array to a string (with newline characters and everything)??? (I though I had it figured out, but maybe I don't understand how your method works well enough)

Comment: What about `Arrays.deepToString(yourMergedArray);` ?

Comment: Never mind, they still print out on top of each other (even if I use my original method, as you suggested above).